# Android: Google Calendar API: how to execute create event method?

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

am using [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) . I created very simple `createEvent` method. Now i want to call `createEvent` method after my `createEventButton` is pressed. I heard that  I need to call `createEvent` through an AsyncTask, the question is how to do that?

`createEvent` method:

```
    public   void createEvent(){

        Event event = new Event();
        DateTime startDateTime=new DateTime(eventStart.getText().toString());

        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

        event.setStart(start);


        DateTime endDateTime= new DateTime(eventEnd.getText().toString());

        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

        event.setStart(end);

        String calendarId = "primary";


        try {
            mService.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I need to call `createEvent` from here:

```
    createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { }});
```

This  listener is in my `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for actual code on how to use the AsyncTask follow [this Github sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android/AsyncInsertCalendar.java):

```
class AsyncInsertCalendar extends CalendarAsyncTask {

  private final Calendar entry;

  AsyncInsertCalendar(CalendarSampleActivity calendarSample, Calendar entry) {
    super(calendarSample);
    this.entry = entry;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
    Calendar calendar = client.calendars().insert(entry).setFields(CalendarInfo.FIELDS).execute();
    model.add(calendar);
  }
}
```

[CalendarAsyncTask](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/android/CalendarAsyncTask.java) is the user-made class which extends AsyncTask.

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to use it, with my  method?Thanks